# Requirement in Snowflake - cummulative string aggregation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi All I am new to Snowflake.
I wanted to know how to get the out-put like below in Snowflake/SQL.

Data that we have

| id | session_id | event_custom_name | event_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5496 | 4621 | start | 26-02-2022 05:40:32 AM |
| 5496 | 4621 | SelectBank | 26-02-2022 05:41:41 AM |
| 5496 | 4621 | login | 26-02-2022 05:41:48 AM |
| 5496 | 4621 | end | 26-02-2022 05:41:52 AM |

Need o/p like below

| id | session_id | event_custom_name | event_date | event_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5496 | 4621 | start | 26-02-2022 05:40:32 AM | start |
| 5496 | 4621 | SelectBank | 26-02-2022 05:41:41 AM | start,SelectBank |
| 5496 | 4621 | login | 26-02-2022 05:41:48 AM | start,SelectBank,login |
| 5496 | 4621 | end | 26-02-2022 05:41:52 AM | start,SelectBank,login,end |

And the events in the event_list columns should be disticnt and should be sorted by event_date.

Thanks,
Akshay

Answer (score 1):

The standard windowed [LISTGAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html) cannot be used in this scenario as it works for the entire partition:

```
SELECT *,
      LISTAGG(event_custom_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY event_date) 
                                      OVER(PARTITION BY session_id) AS result
FROM tab;
```

[image]

---

Cummulative windowed LISTAGG could be achieved by using [Tabular JavaScript UDFs (UDTFs)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html):

Sample Data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(
    id INT,     
    session_id INT,
    event_custom_name TEXT,
    event_date TIMESTAMP)
AS
          SELECT 5496   ,4621 ,'start'      ,'2022-02-26T05:40:32'::TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT 5496   ,4621 ,'SelectBank' ,'2022-02-26T05:41:41'::TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT 5496   ,4621 ,'login'      ,'2022-02-26T05:41:48'::TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT 5496   ,4621 ,'end'        ,'2022-02-26T05:41:52'::TIMESTAMP;
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate (input TEXT, sep TEXT)
RETURNS table (output TEXT)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
IMMUTABLE
AS '
{
  initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
       this.result = "";
       this.count = 0;
    },
  processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {     
       if (this.count == 0) {
        this.result = this.result.concat(row.INPUT);
       }
       else {
            this.result = this.result.concat(row.SEP, row.INPUT);
       }
       this.count += 1;
       
       rowWriter.writeRow({OUTPUT: this.result});           
   },
   
   finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {
       this.result = "";
       this.count = 0;
    }
 }
 ';
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab,  
    TABLE(aggregate(event_custom_name, ',') 
    OVER(PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY event_date))
ORDER BY session_id, event_date;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lukasz Szozda thanks for your answer.

do you know if we can use distinct in that function.
like here if we need the distinct output values

Comment: @akshaymajithia There are two options 1) use subquery to remove duplicates with `QUALIFY` 2) extend the TUDF to handle duplicates in costs of performance.